# How do you give an overall title to a seaborn lattice plot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I don't mean the title that appears above each of the sub-plots.  I mean a single title at the top of the figure.  I know this is basic.  I figured a search would find something pretty quickly, but I couldn't find anything.  The "set" function has a "title" keyword, but that changes the titles at the top of the various subplots.

Comment: Please add your contribution what you already tried and what is the problem

Comment: `plt.set_suptitle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `g.fig.suptitle('COMMON TITLE')` like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time", row="smoker",height=2,aspect=1) #g is the resulting facet grid object
g=g.map(plt.hist,'total_bill')
g.fig.suptitle('COMMON TITLE') #set your title here
plt.show()
```

OUTPUT:
[image]